# static deploy not taking correct files to Pub/Static folders

Tags: magento2, cli, static-content

I've made an update to one of my scss files, and updated the corresponding css file, in the web/css folder of my theme but when I re-run static deploy for en_GB it's not taking the new changes forward, it's still the pre-change version. I'm on Magento ver. 2.1.3.

I've run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

And then

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But it's still bringing the wrong files even if I delete the scss and css file from the pub/static web/css folder and re-run the commands.

I've checked and the server definitely has my changes in the theme web/css folder.

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Are you running Varnish? If so, try manually clearing that

Comment: No Varnish is not installed on the server.

Comment: Make sure it's not browser cache by accessing the page in incognito/private mode.

Comment: No you misunderstand, actually looking at the file in the pub/static folder it is wrong, I can see that it is missing the new CSS.